# getElementsByClassName problems with if statement

Tags: javascript, html

can anyone help with this? i can't seem to figure out why it wont work. thanks.

```
<p class="largetext">GGS</p>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
                var textY = document.getElementsByClassName("largetext")
                for(var i = 0; i < textY.length; i++){if (2 > 1)


                    {textY[i].innerHTML = "passed"; }                                                  
                    else {
                    textY[i].innerHTML = "failed";}}) 
            </script>
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you seeing an error?

Comment: What's the point of `if (2 > 1)`?

Comment: @DBS when the function is activated nothing happens

Comment: @j08691 i've broken it up into simpler parts to get the one issue fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){` should be closed with `});` and not with `}`.
Here is your code:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
                var textY = document.getElementsByClassName("largetext");
                for(var i = 0; i < textY.length; i++){
                   if (2 > 1) {
                    textY[i].innerHTML = "passed";
                   } else {
                    textY[i].innerHTML = "failed";
                   }
                }
            });
```

```css
.largetext {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
<div class="largetext"></div>
```

Comment: Legend! thanks, i can't believe i didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in your code you have missed closing curly braces for the function that's why it was throwing error.

```css
.largetext{min-height: 200vh}
```

```html
<p class="largetext">GGS</p>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
                var textY = document.getElementsByClassName("largetext")
                for(var i = 0; i < textY.length; i++){
                if (2 > 1){
                textY[i].innerHTML = "passed";
                }                                                  
                    else {
                    textY[i].innerHTML = "failed";
                    }
               }
               
               }) 
            </script>
```